# eclipse setting questions

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, settings

```
1. Can we make eclipse automatically refresh its buffer?
```

When we make changes to project files behind eclipse's back, eclipse won't update its buffer automatically. Instead, we have to manually click `Refresh`. When we forget to do so, we might be running old code.

```
2. Can we make eclipse to eliminate automatically the
   leading whitespaces in source code files?
```

Auto indention in eclipse is inserting whitespaces to source code files. Each time we leave a line empty, leading whitespaces are left over. Consider the following code:

```
1 public void f() {
2   // init
3   a = b;
4
5   // do it
6   for (...) { ... }
7 }
```

After typing line 3, we hit `ENTER`. At this point, we realize that we want to separate the different logical sections of the code, so we hit `ENTER` again. It's obviously a reasonable thing to do, but unfortunately there are some leading whitespaces left over on line 4. Source code control tools (e.g., `git`) are not happy with that. So can we remove them from inside eclipse?

```
3. Can we save preference settings across workspaces?
```

Every time I create a new workspace, I need to change the preference settings. For example, I would typically make the fonts bigger. It's sort of redundant. So can I reuse existing settings?

Comment: what problems does git have with blank lines that have whitespace? (I'm not a git afficiando, and I want to avoid those problems myself)

Answer (score 3):

**3. Can we save preference settings across workspaces?**

You can [export the old workspace preferences and import into new workspace](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/timpandexp.htm). Another read: [Create New Eclipse Workspace - With All Your Old Settings](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first and second questions:
1. You can turn on automatic workspace refreshing which will call refresh every 2 seconds or so, I'm lazy to find it so here is a [link](http://www.foosel.org/blog/2009/06/cool_eclipse_stuff_autorefresh) with the shot of the prefs tab where you can set it.
2.You can set your own code formatting template, also in the preferences. And then add formatting to the save actions. You can easily google how to do these.

The third one is already answered well by Pangea.

Answer (score 0):

Through Eclipse preferences menu (editor/appearence), there is a checkbox to remove trailing whitespaces.

If you want to do a (barbarian) backup of your settings, you can zip your workspace (eclipse must be shut down before this).

If you want to save your settings only, you can zip only the eclipse files/folders in the workspace folder, ignoring the source code.

I'm aware with the second method, since I use it weekly .

Comment: There is also a menu "scan for external changes" (i can't verify since my Eclipse is not on this computer). Click in your tree view (project files) then press F5 or right-click -> refresh.